# How do I padding fontawesome icons? - React

Tags: css, jsx

I have icons in the div that is in my JSX code. I want a small gap between these icons. Can you help?

```
<div className={styles.icon}>
    <FontAwesomeIcon
        onClick={addToList}
        className={styles["Plus"]}
        icon={faPlus}
    />
    <Link to={`/detail/${recipe.uri.split("_")[1]}`}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon className={styles["Utensils"]} icon={faUtensils} />
    </Link>
</div>
```

module.css code

```
.icon {
    text-decoration: none;
    .Plus {
        color: green;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .Utensils {
        color: green;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple add margin to Utensils class

```
 .Utensils {
    color: green;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 5px
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Add an extra class to these icons and add some extra margin:

```
.icons{
  margin: 10px;
}
```